# How can I solve the issue of pybabel-0.0.0.dev0 disappearing after installation with pip?

Tags: python, pip

I need to use pybabel library to make locale files.
I run: `pip install pybabel`
And I see that the version pybabel-0.0.0.dev0 is being installed
Here is the documentation https://babel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cmdline.html
Where did she disappear to and what to do? The developer threw people and destroyed the project

Searched and found nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using the correct installation command. The project `pybabel` on Pypi does not seem to be related to the python interface of `Babel` for which you are reading the documentation. See the [Installation section](https://babel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html) of the docs that you have linked:

> enter the following command to get Babel installed in your virtualenv:

```
$ pip install Babel
```

**General Note**

While it is often true that the name of the package you `import` in python is the same as the name of the project on Pypi, there are also many exceptions. It is always advisable to both check the documentation of the package you try to install for the correct command and/or check the PyPi project page if you are looking at the correct package